# Mapeamento de classes com FluentAPI e Entityframework C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent-api

Tabela Pais, Estado, Cidade;

Um país pode ter vários estados e um estado pode ter apenas 1 pais;

> Estado->Pais : 1:N

Uma cidade pode ter apenas um estado e um estado pode ter várias cidades.

> Cidade|Estado 1:N
>
> Gostaria de saber como deveria montar esse relacionamento na minha classe do C#. Como as coleção de dados e a parte de relacionamento de FK, estou meio confuso como é realizado isso.

```
public class Pais : EntityBase
{
    public Pais()
    {
        Estados = new List<Estado>();
    }

    public override long Handle { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Estado> Estados { get; set; }
}

public class PaisMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Pais>
{
    public PaisMap()
    {
        ToTable("Pais");            
        HasKey(x => x.Handle);
        Property(x => x.Descricao).HasMaxLength(150).IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.Sigla).HasMaxLength(3).IsRequired();
        HasMany(x => x.Estados);
    }
}

public class Estado : EntityBase
{
    public Estado()
    {
        Pais = new Pais();
        Cidades = new List<Cidade>();
    }

    public override long Handle { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
    public long PaisHandle { get; set; }
    public virtual Pais Pais { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Cidade> Cidades { get; set; }
}

public class EstadoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Estado>
{
    public EstadoMap()
    {
        ToTable("Estado");            
        HasKey(x => x.Handle);
        Property(x => x.Descricao).HasMaxLength(150).IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.Sigla).HasMaxLength(2).IsRequired();

        HasRequired(x => x.Pais)
            .WithMany(x => x.Estados)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.PaisHandle);

        HasMany(x => x.Cidades);
    }
}

public class Cidade : EntityBase
{
    public Cidade()
    {
        Pais = new Pais();
        Estado = new Estado();
    }

    public override long Handle { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
    public long PaisHandle { get; set; }
    public virtual Pais Pais { get; set; }
    public long EstadoHandle { get; set; }
    public virtual Estado Estado { get; set; }
}

public class CidadeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cidade>
{
    public CidadeMap()
    {  
        ToTable("Cidade");            
        HasKey(x => x.Handle);
        Property(x => x.Descricao).HasMaxLength(150).IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.Sigla).HasMaxLength(2).IsRequired();

        HasRequired(x => x.Estado)
            .WithMany(x => x.Cidades)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.EstadoHandle);            
    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi a necessidade de cidade está vinculada diretamente com o País. Pois através de um determinado estado já está vinculado ao país de toda forma.

Comment: @Cleidson_eng, tirando esse relacionamento que não ficou tão correto, gostaria de saber como faço para realizar o mapeamento, pois estou fazendo da forma que está no código e não da certo, gostaria qual a forma correta de fazer mapeamento usando o CodeFirst e FluentAPI

Comment: Veja Esse link Tem exemplo que pode lhe ajudar:
[ Parte 1](http://netcoders.com.br/mapeamento-com-entity-framework-code-first-fluent-api-parte-1/) [Parte 2](http://netcoders.com.br/mapeamento-com-entity-framework-code-first-fluent-api-parte-2/)

Answer (score 1):

Olha, evite utilizar a `FluentAPI` para os casos mais basicos, neste caso é melhor usar `DataAnnotations`.:

Segue abaixo uma implementação, note que na EntityBase estou à utilizar o [`EntityFramework.Triggers`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Triggers/) para automatizar a atualização de alguns campos.

```
// Não esqueça do abstract
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    // Acredite, colocar o ID na classe base não é uma boa.
    // Como você faria com uma entidade com chave multipla
    // public Guid EntityID { get; set; }


    public Guid UsuarioCriacaoID { get; set; }
    public Guid UsuarioAtualizacaoID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataAtualizacao { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("UsuarioCriacaoID")]
    public virtual Pais UsuarioCriacao { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UsuarioAtualizacaoID")]
    public virtual Pais UsuarioAtualizacao { get; set; }    

    static EntityBase()
    {
        Triggers<EntityBase>.Inserting += entry =>
        {                
            var contexto = entry.Context as MyContext;
            entry.Entity.DataCriacao = DateTime.Now;
            entry.Entity.DataAtualizacao = DateTime.Now;
            entry.Entity.UsuarioCriacaoID = contexto.UsuarioID;
            entry.Entity.UsuarioAtualizacaoID = contexto.UsuarioID;
            entry.Entity.IsDeleted = false;
        };
        Triggers<EntityBase>.Updating += entry =>
        {
            var contexto = entry.Context as MyContext;
            entry.Entity.DataCriacao = DateTime.Now;
            entry.Entity.DataAtualizacao = DateTime.Now;
            entry.Entity.UsuarioCriacaoID = contexto.UsuarioID;
            entry.Entity.UsuarioAtualizacaoID = contexto.UsuarioID;
            entry.Entity.IsDeleted = false;
        };
        Triggers<EntityBase>.Deleting += entry =>
        {
            var contexto = entry.Context as Contexto;
            entry.Entity.IsDeleted = true;
            entry.Cancel = true;
        };
    }
}

[Table("Usuarios")]
public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UsuarioID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index(IsUnique=true)]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Logon { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public byte[] Senha { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(16)]
    public byte[] Salt { get; set; }
}

[Table("Paises")]
public class Pais : EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public Guid PaisID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(3)]
    public string Sigla { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Estado> Estados { get; set; } = new List<Estado>();
}

[Table("Estados")]
public class Estado : EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public Guid EstadoID { get; set; }
    public Guid PaisID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(2)]
    public long PaisHandle { get; set; }

    // Utilize o Atributo ForeignKey apenas se a propriedade usada configurar o relacionamento tenha um nome diferente da Key da Entidade Referenciada.
    // [ForeignKey("PaisID")]
    public virtual Pais Pais { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cidade> Cidades { get; set; } new List<Cidade>();
}

[Table("Cidades")]
public class Cidade : EntityBase
{
    public Cidade()
    {
        Pais = new Pais();
        Estado = new Estado();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid CidadeID { get; set; }
    public Guid EstadoID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(2)]
    public string Sigla { get; set; }

    // Utilize o Atributo ForeignKey apenas se a propriedade usada configurar o relacionamento tenha um nome diferente da Key da Entidade Referenciada.
    // [ForeignKey("EstadoID")]
    public virtual Estado Estado { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public Guid UsuarioID { get; private set; }
    public MyContext(Guid usuarioID)
    {
        this.UsuarioID = usuarioID;
    }

    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Pais> Paises { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Estado> Estados { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Cidade> Cidades { get; set; } 

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    { 
        modelBuilder.Filter("IsDeleted", (EntityBase d) => d.IsDeleted, false);
        // Faça aqui os mapeamentos que não conseguir fazer por DataAnnotations, como por exemplo algo especifico para o SGBD.
    } 
}
```

Por fim, se decidir usar Soft Delete como no exemplo acima, será interessante usar algum esquema de filtro global, como por exemplo o [`EntityFramework.DynamicFilters`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters/)

**EDIT - Sobre o Fluent API**

Vamos olhar apenas o seguinte trecho de codigo.:

```
public class EstadoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Estado>
{
    public EstadoMap()
    {
        ...
        HasMany(x => x.Cidades);
    }
}

public class CidadeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cidade>
{
    public CidadeMap()
    {  
        ...
        HasRequired(x => x.Estado)
            .WithMany(x => x.Cidades)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.EstadoHandle);            
    }
}
```

ao fazer `HasRequired(x => x.Estado).WithMany(x => x.Cidades).HasForeignKey(x => x.EstadoHandle)` no `CidadeMap` você já está mapeamento os dois lados do relacionamento, então chamar `HasMany(x => x.Cidades)` no `EstadoMap` é desnecessário, apenas remova este tipo de mapeamento.

```
public class PaisMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Pais>
{
    public PaisMap()
    {
        ToTable("Pais");            
        HasKey(x => x.Handle);
        Property(x => x.Descricao).HasMaxLength(150).IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.Sigla).HasMaxLength(3).IsRequired();
    }
}

public class EstadoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Estado>
{
    public EstadoMap()
    {
        ToTable("Estado");            
        HasKey(x => x.Handle);
        Property(x => x.Descricao).HasMaxLength(150).IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.Sigla).HasMaxLength(2).IsRequired();
        HasRequired(x => x.Pais).WithMany(x => x.Estados).HasForeignKey(x => x.PaisHandle);
    }
}

public class CidadeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cidade>
{
    public CidadeMap()
    {  
        ToTable("Cidade");            
        HasKey(x => x.Handle);
        Property(x => x.Descricao).HasMaxLength(150).IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.Sigla).HasMaxLength(2).IsRequired();
        HasRequired(x => x.Estado).WithMany(x => x.Cidades).HasForeignKey(x => x.EstadoHandle);            
    }
}
```

Comment: compreendi totalmente sua dica, só que essas classes peguei apenas de exemplo para mostrar aqui, tem muitas tabelas, e pelo que estudei e ouvi falar bastante, é que é importante e uma ótima pratica, deixar a Entity totalmente sem regra de negócio, ou seja, usar a fluent API para realizar isso, Estou tentando fazer aqui mais está dando erro na Migrations. Vou abrir outro tópico para ver se alguém pode me ajudar no problema. Obrigado pela Solução onde realmente era os relacionamentos das tabelas

Comment: @NicolaBogar não vi regras de negocio no modelo acima, apenas regras inerentes à Modelagem, então não estamos a ferir este principio..

Comment: Correto, mas nesse caso ai de cima que você mesmo passou, você poderia me dar um exemplo usando FluentAPI?

Comment: @NicolaBogar pronto.